# Can't ping or connect successfully from Intellij to docker postgres container

Tags: postgresql, docker, intellij-idea, database-connection, ping

I am trying to connect my docker postgres database to my Intellij. I have created the container and a database inside. The container is running and i can create tables and everything. In my Intellij, on the bottom left, in the "Services" i can see the container and all of its details. All i need is the connect the postgresql database but i'm running into some problems.

Tried all of these while container is running:

ping IpAddressOfContainer -> "Request timed out."

telnet IpAddressOfContainer Port -> "Connection failed"

Connecting to Intellij while "Host: localhost" and "Database: student(a database in the container)"
-> "FATAL: database "student" does not exist".

Connecting to Intellij while "Host: localhost" and "Database: postgres(default)"
-> Successful but i receive a database i created 1 month ago in DataGrip.

Connecting to Intellij while "Host: IpAddress of Container" and "Database: student(a database in the container)"
-> "The connection attempt failed".

Connecting to Intellij while "Host: IpAddress of Container" and "Database: postgres(default)"
-> "The connection attempt failed".

Comment: Hi! Could you please specify the command you use to run the container? The problem could be related to the ports' mapping, make sure it is set up correctly.

Comment: (The container-private IP address is unreachable in many environments and you shouldn't ever need to look it up.  ping(1) sends packets using a very-low-level protocol, ICMP, and it isn't really useful as a diagnostic tool here.  The `psql` command-line tool connecting to your container's published port would be the simplest validation.)

Comment: Hi @OlgaM. This is the command i use:  docker run -d --rm --name postgresdb -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres -p 5432:5432 -v pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres

Comment: @DavidMaze thank you for the valuable information. Now that you are saying that, i also think the psql command should be enough of a validation. But why can't i find it in my Intellij?

Comment: PROBLEM SOLVED!!! i changed the port of the host to 5433. Idk why that works, but i guess that port was somehow used or idk. Thank you!